# Subgraph with same number of edges as original graph

Tags: graph-theory

I currently have an efficient algorithm for generating the subgraphs of a graph (using the boost library). My question, the answer to which though seemingly obvious, is more on the theoretical side: can a subgraph S of an undirected, unweighted graph G have the same number of edges as G, excluding G itself? There are no constraints on the number of vertices that S can have.

My first guess to the above question would have to be No, but that's based on "common-sense and hand-waving" rather than a rigorous mathematical argument. Does anyone have an alternative answer or know of a mathematical set of criterion that subgraphs must obey?

Thanks,
VV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If G has a isolated vertex (one with no edges in or out) then the subgraph of G obtained by removing that vertex has the same number of edges but strictly fewer vertices.

Suppose G has no isolated vertices. Any (strict i.e. not G) subgraph of G must either contain all the vertices of G or omit some vertex `v` of G. If the former, it cannot have all the edges of G or it would be G. If the latter, since `v` has at least one incident edge `e` (by assumption), the subgraph cannot contain `e` since it does not contain both of its endpoints; namely, it does not contain `v`. Hence any subgraph of G has strictly fewer edges than G itself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - consider a graph `G` with an [isolated vertex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#Adjacency_and_degree). The removal of this vertex gives a proper subgraph of `G` whose edge set is exactly the same as that of `G`.

If the graph has no isolated vertices, then the answer is "no": when you remove a vertex, all edges [incident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#Adjacency_and_degree) to the vertex get removed. Since each vertex has at least one such edge (remember: no isolated vertices), the number of edges is reduced.